# mutt mailboxes setting in multiple-file configuration

Tags: mutt, mailbox

I have an issue I don't understand when setting my mailboxes in mutt. If I use a single configuration file, the following works fine:

```
mailboxes +myaccount/INBOX \
          +myaccount/Drafts \
          +myaccount/Blah \
          +myaccount/Sent \

macro index c "<change-folder>?<toggle-mailboxes>" "open a different folder"
macro pager c "<change-folder>?<toggle-mailboxes>" "open a different folder"
```

Now, I want to put mailboxes in a separate configuration file (to use the same muttrc on different machines). But if I put the mailboxes command in `~/.mutt/mboxconf` and the macro in `~/.mutt/bindings`, then the macro does not work any more. How come? Is `mailboxes` some kind of a local configuration variable?

(I noticed the same problem with the sidebar patch. It only works if mailboxes is defined in `~/.muttrc`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't include the `\` after `+myaccount/Sent \` in the separate config file. Or at least, the following works for me:

`~/.muttrc` contains:

```
source ~/.mutt/mboxconf
source ~/.mutt/bindings
```

And `~/.mutt/mboxconf` contains:

```
mailboxes +myaccount/INBOX \
          +myaccount/Drafts \
          +myaccount/Blah \
          +myaccount/Sent
```

And `~/.mutt/bindings` contains:

```
macro index c "<change-folder>?<toggle-mailboxes>" "open a different folder"
macro pager c "<change-folder>?<toggle-mailboxes>" "open a different folder"
```

But as soon as I add a `\` after `+myaccount/Sent` the macros no longer work.